# Comprofiler Plugins call using Joomla model

Tags: php, joomla

How to call comprofiler plugin in Joomla models or controllers?

I tried this:

```
global $_PLUGINS;

$_PLUGINS->trigger('onAfterUserUpdate', 'pul_getChanges', array(&$_POST, 1));
```

but it is not working.

Comment: When you have Joomla questions, please post them @ [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the Joomla way to call a plugin function

```
//Import the plugin that you need    
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('group', 'plugin_name');

//You have to instantiate JEventDispatcher class which will has trigger method to call that plugin function. 

JEventDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger(
    'onAfterUserUpdate', 
    array(
        &$_POST, 
        1
    )
);
```

So in `trigger` function it takes two parameters where first one is the function name and the second is the parameter data given in array format.

Comment: The "STFU operator" (`@`) should be avoided.  `$_POST` is a SUPERGLOBAL, so it should always be present (unless Joomla unsets it).  Did you mean: `&$_POST` as the OP has written?